# Disable, hide or remove close "X" button in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to show a GUI to client, but I don't want to give the possibility to the client to close the window through the `[X]` button.

How do I disable, hide or remove the close `[X]` button of Tkinter window?

I found the following answers:

1. [Python Tkinter “X” button control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295270/python-tkinter-x-button-control-the-button-that-close-the-window)
2. [Removing minimize/maximize buttons in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969870/removing-minimize-maximize-buttons-in-tkinter)

However, these posts are not answering my question. I want to disable, hide or completely remove the `[X]` button.

When I use `protocol`:

```
def __init__(self):
    Frame.__init__(self, bg = "black")
    self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.doSomething)
    self.pack(expand = 1, fill = BOTH)

def doSomething(self):
    if showinfo.askokcancel("Quit?", "Are you sure you want to quit?"):
        self.quit()
```

I receive the following error:

> `self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.doSomething)`
>       AttributeError: 'GUI' object has no attribute 'protocol'

Comment: What OS are you using? I believe it is OS specific. In most cases you can close window just by pressing Alt+F4 even if there was no X button.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: [This might be relevant](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182914/how-to-disable-closing-a-window). It is not so pythonic question *per se*.

Comment: Note that the example you link is using `root.protocol`, like in [TkInter's documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm). I guess your `GUI` class is not the root window.

Comment: I define class like class myClass(Frame): , I define above code in this class , so this is act as my root class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with calling the `protocol` method is that it's a method on a root window but your GUI object is not a root window. Your code will work if you call the protocol method on the root window.

As for how to remove the button completely -- there's no method to simply remove that one button. You can remove all of the window manager buttons and frame by setting the `overrideredirect` flag.