# Python tkinter: How can I ensure only ONE child window is created onclick and not a new window every time the button is clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently learning tkinter and have come to a dead end.
Each time I click one of the buttons in my GUI (after typing 'username' and 'password' into the log in screen) a new child window is created and appears. As it should. What I would now like to do is to ensure that only one window is created and any subsequent clicks do not create yet more windows. How could this be done?

```
from tkinter import *

class Main():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Main Window")

        self.button1 = Button(self.master, text="Click Me 1", command = self.Open1)
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.button2 = Button(self.master, text="Click Me 2", command = self.Open2)
        self.button2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.button3 = Button(self.master, text="Close", command = self.Close)
        self.button3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

    def Login(self):

        login_win = Toplevel(self.master)
        login_window = Login(login_win)
        login_window.Focus()
        #main_window.Hide()


    def Open1(self):
        second_window = Toplevel(self.master)
        window2 = Second(second_window)

    def Open2(self):
        third_window = Toplevel(self.master)
        window3 = Third(third_window)

    def Close(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    #def Hide(self):
        #self.master.withdraw()

    #def Appear(self):
        #self.master.deiconify()


class Second():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Child 1 of Main")
        self.master.geometry("300x300")
        self.button4 = Button(self.master, text="Click Me 1", command = self.Open_Child)
        self.button4.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)


    def Open_Child(self):
        second_child_window = Toplevel(self.master)
        window4 = Second_Child(second_child_window)

class Third():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("300x300")
        self.master.title("Child 2 of Main")

class Second_Child():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("400x300")
        self.master.title("Child of 'Child 1 of Main'")

class Login():
    def __init__(self, window):

        self.window = window
        self.window.title("Current Library")

        Label(self.window, text="Log in to use this program:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.userbox=Entry(self.window, width=20, bg="light green")
        self.userbox.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.passbox=Entry(self.window, width=20, bg="light green")
        self.passbox.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

        Button(self.window, text="Submit", width=5, command=self.clicked).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

    def Focus(self):
        self.window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
        self.window.grab_set()

    def clicked(self):
        username = self.userbox.get()
        password = self.passbox.get()
        if password == "password" and username == "username":
            self.correct = True
            self.window.grab_release()
            self.window.destroy()
        else:
            pass

root_window = Tk()
root_window.iconbitmap(default='transparent.ico')
root_window.geometry("200x100")

main_window = Main(root_window)
main_window.Login()

root_window.mainloop()
```

Inside the functions which are called when the buttons are clicked could I add an IF statement?: IF window object does not exist then instantiate window object ELSE pass.

```
def Open1(self):
    if window2 == False:
        second_window = Toplevel(self.master)
        window2 = Second(second_window)
    else:
        pass
```

If this is the correct logic then how can I check if a window object has already been created because the above doesn't work as I am referencing the object before it is created?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize the child window variable in Main's `__init__`.

```
self.child_window = None
```

Then you can check whether it exists in `Open1`.

```
def Open1(self):
    if not self.child_window:
        self.child_window = Second(Toplevel(self.master))
```

By the way, if you intend for Second to act like its own window, it's a bit awkward that you have to create a Toplevel every time you want to create a Second. Conventionally, you would make `Second` a subclass of `Toplevel`, so it can be created on its own. Something like:

```
class Second(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kargs):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master, *args, **kargs)
        #rest of initialization goes here. 
        #Use `self` everywhere you previously used `self.master`.
```

Now you could just do:

```
def Open1(self):
    if not self.child_window:
        self.child_window = Second(self.master)
```

Comment: Another related question: How could I then reassign 'None' into variable 'self.child_window' when the child window is closed (exited with red cross)?

Comment: You can register a callback function that gets called when the window is closed. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295270/python-tkinter-x-button-control-the-button-that-close-the-window) for more information.